# AngularJS custom directive with hide function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to create an AngularJS custom directive that hides an element if it's in a variable.

For example, I have three links generated from the directive:

- Home
- About
- Hide

I want to hide the "Hide" link.

Here is my view:

```
<ul>
  <menu link="Home"></menu>
  <menu link="About"></menu>
  <menu link="Hide"></menu>
</ul>
```

...directive:

```
app.directive('menu', function() {
    return {
      scope: {
          link: "@"
      },
      template: '<li ng-hide="hideMenu(link)">{{link}}</li>',
      controller: function($scope) {
        var hideLink = 'Hide';
        function hideMenu(link) {
          if (hideLink == link) {
            return true;
          }
        }
      }
    };
});
```

[...and Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/X5jYrHP093SihKFVTwpm?p=preview).

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For your function to be available in your template, it has to be in your scope. Here's the updated code:

```
app.directive('menu', function() {
return {
  scope: {
      link: "@"
  },
  template: '<li ng-hide="hideMenu(link)">{{link}}</li>',
  controller: function($scope) {
    var hideLink = 'Hide';
    $scope.hideMenu = function(link) {
      if (hideLink == link) {
        return true;
      }
    }
  }
};
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Add to your controller in directive `$scope.hideMenu = hideMenu;`

```
app.directive('menu', function() {
    return {
      scope: {
          link: "@"
      },
      template: '<li ng-hide="hideMenu(link)">{{link}}</li>',
      controller: function($scope) {
        var hideLink = 'Hide';
        function hideMenu(link) {
          if (hideLink == link) {
            return true;
          }
        }

        $scope.hideMenu = hideMenu;
      }
    };
});
```